# Acronis Migrate Easy Work With Windows 7

Tags: clone, acronis-trueimage

I recently purchase a bigger seagate sshd drive to replace the currently smaller one in my laptop.  I have been looking around for free alternatives that will clone everything including the OS (Windows 7) so that I can disassemble and install the new drive and it will act exactly the same just more free space.

Now I see the website says Windows 7 is not supported, however I have seem some recent posts that lead me to think it still may work.

I have the new drive connected through a usb to sata cable.  Is there a different free alternative?  Or is it buck up and pay for Acronis True Image?

Comment: We don't provide software recomendations.  THere are dozens of free and paid software to clone a hdd.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the heads up.  Could you confirm then whether Acornis Migrate Easy will work with cloning Windows 7?

Comment: If it installs it should work.